# How to check if table elements within cell array are equal, return result for each row

Tags: matlab

I am trying to check if the elements in a column within a table, within a cell are equal to another set of data stored in a similar manner.

I have tried using `==` however it returns

> error "Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'table'.".

```
% load tables into cell array
p{1} = readtable('1.csv');
p{2} = readtable('2.csv');
p{3} = readtable('3.csv');
p{4} = readtable('4.csv');
p{5} = readtable('5.csv');
p{6} = readtable('6.csv');
p{7} = readtable('7.csv');
p{8} = readtable('8.csv');
p{9} = readtable('9.csv');
p{10} = readtable('10.csv');
p{11} = readtable('11.csv');
p{12} = readtable('12.csv');
p{13} = readtable('13.csv');
p{14} = readtable('14.csv');
p{15} = readtable('15.csv');

for i = 1:15 
    % predict 'output' of table data using model, for each table
    predict{i} = trainedModel.predictFcn(p{i});

    % check if predicted data 'output' is equal to actual 'output' (which 
      %is stored in column five of tables, for each table
    results{i} = (p{i}(:,5) == predict{i}(:,1));

    % determine percentage fit of predict results vs output for each 
      %table
    percentagefit[i,1] = (sum(results{i})/length(results{i}));
end
```

As expected, '`predict`' returns a cell of 1x15 with 15 tables inside (1 table per cell with according predictions).

I expect that the output of '`results`' should be a cell (size 1x15) with 15 tables stored of according table size. At the moment it is throwing the

> "Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'table'." error.

I expect that the percentage fit will return a table of 15x1, i have not been able to get any results yet due to '`results`' error.

Comment: Tables [can be indexed](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) similarly to cell arrays, so something like `(p{i}{:,5} == predict{i}{:,1})` should work as desired. A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Do you want an element-wise comparison giving a logical vector, or just a single True or False value? If the latter, have you tried `isequal(table1, table2)` in place of `table1 == table2`?